# Less equal than specific date query not working on equal date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.No_Registrasi) as Jumlah, b.Nama_Negara, a.Tanggal_Reg
FROM tb_registrasi a
JOIN tb_negara_tujuan b
   ON a.ID_Negara = b.ID_Negara
WHERE a.Tanggal_Reg >= '2016-02-01' AND a.Tanggal_Reg <= '2016-03-01'
GROUP BY b.Nama_Negara
```

The result is:
[image: result]

But when im change to:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.No_Registrasi) as Jumlah, b.Nama_Negara, a.Tanggal_Reg
FROM tb_registrasi a
JOIN tb_negara_tujuan b
   ON a.ID_Negara = b.ID_Negara
WHERE a.Tanggal_Reg >= '2016-02-01' AND a.Tanggal_Reg <= '2016-02-29' //this one
GROUP BY b.Nama_Negara
```

It didnt show any result, what im trying is to select data from between 2 different dates, but when when there's data on the date at the end of the month, it didnt show the data. say i have 5 data that registered to date 2016-04-30, when im selecting data from 2016-04-01 to 2016-04-30 it didnt show any result.
I hope you guys understand what i mean, thanks in advance.

Comment: `2016-02-29` consider as `2016-02-29 00:00:00`, so the condition fails and no data returns

Comment: use "date(a.Tanggal_Reg)" in Where condition to extrct date only from timestamp!

Comment: @Arulkumar thanks for the answer, i didn't know that if you dont add the time it will consider as 00:00:00

Comment: @Kunal thanks, this is what i need, i just need the date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `DATE` Function to columns

```
WHERE DATE(a.Tanggal_Reg) >= '2016-02-01' AND DATE(a.Tanggal_Reg) <= '2016-02-29'
```

or use between

```
WHERE DATE(a.Tanggal_Reg) BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-29'
```

So your query will be:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.No_Registrasi) as Jumlah, b.Nama_Negara, a.Tanggal_Reg
FROM tb_registrasi a
JOIN tb_negara_tujuan b
   ON a.ID_Negara = b.ID_Negara
WHERE DATE(a.Tanggal_Reg) >= '2016-02-01' AND DATE(a.Tanggal_Reg) <= '2016-02-29' //this one
GROUP BY b.Nama_Negara
```

or with between

```
SELECT COUNT(a.No_Registrasi) as Jumlah, b.Nama_Negara, a.Tanggal_Reg
    FROM tb_registrasi a
    JOIN tb_negara_tujuan b
       ON a.ID_Negara = b.ID_Negara
    WHERE DATE(a.Tanggal_Reg) BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-29' 
    GROUP BY b.Nama_Negara
```

Comment: this is what i want, since i only needing the date only not with the time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following query?

```
SELECT COUNT(a.No_Registrasi) as Jumlah, b.Nama_Negara, a.Tanggal_Reg
FROM tb_registrasi a
JOIN tb_negara_tujuan b
ON a.ID_Negara = b.ID_Negara
WHERE a.Tanggal_Reg >= '2016-02-01 00:00:00' AND a.Tanggal_Reg <= '2016-02-29 23:59:59'
GROUP BY b.Nama_Negara
```

Comment: thanks, i didn't know that if i dont add the time it will be considered as 00:00:00 time

Answer (score 1):

You may use `BETWEEN` too as

```
SELECT COUNT(a.No_Registrasi) as Jumlah, b.Nama_Negara, a.Tanggal_Reg
FROM tb_registrasi a
JOIN tb_negara_tujuan b
   ON a.ID_Negara = b.ID_Negara
WHERE a.Tanggal_Reg BETWEEN '2016-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-02-29 23:59:59'
GROUP BY b.Nama_Negara
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have hour's problem. Sql is getting datas between 2016-02-01 00:00:00 and 2016-02-29 00:00:00. And to get a month datas you can get with the next day like that:

```
WHERE a.Tanggal_Reg >= '2016-02-01' AND a.Tanggal_Reg <= '2016-03-01'
```

Or you can try give hours to query:

```
    SELECT COUNT(a.No_Registrasi) as Jumlah, b.Nama_Negara, a.Tanggal_Reg
FROM tb_registrasi a
JOIN tb_negara_tujuan b
   ON a.ID_Negara = b.ID_Negara
WHERE a.Tanggal_Reg >= '2016-02-01 00:00:00' AND a.Tanggal_Reg <= '2016-02-29 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY b.Nama_Negara
```